# Ruby on Rails Mysql2::Error: Table 'pages' already exists: CREATE TABLE `pages` but cannot migrate back

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was trying to run a migration but had missed a line out of t.integer "subject_id" when first trying to run it.

The migration looks like this:

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.integer "subject_id"
        # same as: t.references :subject
        t.string "name"
        t.string "permalink"
        t.integer "position"
        t.boolean "visible", :default => false
        t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("pages", "subject_id")
    add_index("pages", "permalink")
  end

  def down
    drop_table :pages
  end

end
```

The above is now seemingly correct but when I try to run it again I get this:

```
George$ rake db:migrate
== 20150110112705 CreatePages: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:pages)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'pages' already exists: CREATE TABLE `pages` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `subject_id` int(11), `name` varchar(255), `permalink` varchar(255), `position` int(11), `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0, `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150110112705_create_pages.rb:4:in `up'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'pages' already exists: CREATE TABLE `pages` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `subject_id` int(11), `name` varchar(255), `permalink` varchar(255), `position` int(11), `visible` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0, `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150110112705_create_pages.rb:4:in `up'
Mysql2::Error: Table 'pages' already exists
/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150110112705_create_pages.rb:4:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I understand it is obviously saying you are trying to create a table called Pages which already exists as the line I messed up is the one immiediately after the table was created. But I cannot figure out how to have the migration run again with the table already existing. I have tried to comment out the line to create the table but that does not work either.

I am still doing a beginners tutorial in Rails so the above is the only thing I could think of to try.

EDIT: I have now tried Shivam's suggestion but now get the following:

```
== 20150110112657 CreateSubjects: reverting ===================================
-- drop_table(:subjectsend)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'simple_cms_development.subjectsend': DROP TABLE `subjectsend`/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150110112657_create_subjects.rb:13:in `down'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'simple_cms_development.subjectsend': DROP TABLE `subjectsend`
/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150110112657_create_subjects.rb:13:in `down'
Mysql2::Error: Unknown table 'simple_cms_development.subjectsend'
/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20150110112657_create_subjects.rb:13:in `down'
Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
George$
```

Comment: remove table pages from your db or for one migration comment create_table method

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the migration file is exactly the same as it was during running the migration and then rollback the migration like this:

```
rake db:rollback STEP=1 # rollbacks 1 step
```

Once that is done, edit the file accordingly and:

```
rake db:migrate
```

or you can specifically tell the version by:

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=20141222070950 #verison is timestamp from your migration filename
```

**Alternatively**

I can see all you want to do is add a new column `subject_id` to you model table. You can achieve this by running a [standalone migration](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) too:

```
rails generate migration AddSubjectIdToPages subject_id:integer
```

followed by:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I tried the rollback to start with and it was not a success. The error is now included in my original question.

Comment: what is `subjectsend` table? Did you try removing tables directly from your mysql? Piece of advice: When using rails, never directly edit anything from mysql. If you are doing it, it means you are doing it terribly wrong.

Comment: I have no idea. It must have been something I messed up on but I don't believe I was meant to have it there.